# How to see what command a shortcut runs in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, icons

I have an app that I usually start by clicking the icon in my taskbar. How do I see what command is being run when clicking the icon? I want to run the program in the terminal, so I can see the output.

I am not sure what tags I should use for this question.

Comment: first find out the `.desktop` file of the app.. Open the `.desktop` file.. see the command under `Exec=` line

Comment: Depending on your desktop environment, you might right click on the icon and select "Properties" (or similar menu entry). Under "Starter" you will find the command line. If there is a menu entry like "Edit Starter", you could also use that.

Comment: I did find the .desktop file, but I am curious how to find the file just from the icon. If I right click icon, the only option for any icon (unrelated to the specific app) is "Show Details", which just brings up the application in the software center, which doesn't work as most apps I use don't exist in the software center.